# How to draw polyline and polygon using finger on bing map?

Tags: ios, swift, bing-maps

I am developing a social media application in iOS/Swift, I need to implement Bing map so that user can draw or erase geofence (polyline and polygon) anywhere with dragging their finger on Bing map.

How to draw and get dynamic coordinates of polygon?

I am implementing these code but this code takes statics coordinate(latitude and longitude) to draw shape.

```swift
func drawLineOnMap() {
    let center = self.mapView.mapCenter.position

    let geopath = MSGeopath(positions:
        [MSGeoposition(latitude: center.latitude-0.0005, longitude: center.longitude-0.001),
         MSGeoposition(latitude: center.latitude+0.0005, longitude: center.longitude+0.001)])

    let mapPolyline = MSMapPolyline()
    mapPolyline.path = geopath
    mapPolyline.strokeColor = UIColor.black
    mapPolyline.strokeWidth = 3
    mapPolyline.strokeDashed = true

    // Add Polyline to a layer on the map control.
    let linesLayer = MSMapElementLayer()
    linesLayer.zIndex = 1
    linesLayer.elements.add(mapPolyline)
    mapView.layers.add(linesLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the methods you want are LocationFromOffset and OffsetFromLocation on the MapView class. See documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/sdk-native/map-control-api/mapview-class
These methods will convert from screen-space to world coordinates which you can then use to create a MapPolyline or MapPolygon object.